# Grafana alert / value equals zero

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-alerts

I have the prometheus query = `sum by (job) (rate(http_requests_total[5m]))`

Could you tell how can I create alert in grafana when the value is equal zero (longer than given time)

I cannot find proper function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want an alert to fire when the 5m average has been zero for more than 5 minutes:

[image]

If you dislike the `is below 0.01` you can turn the query into a boolean one like so:

```
sum by (job) (rate(http_requests_total[5m])) == bool 0
```

Now you will get a `1` if the rate is 0 and 0 if the rate is not 0.